# How do I restart my python game, or just reset where the player is?

Tags: python, pygame

I want to restart where my player is when the player touches a wall, but before I do that, I want to give them a warning then reset position. I can't do either, though. I recently asked a similar question, and although I got a very good and helpful answer, it wouldn't work. Thank you anyway, Rabbid76. This is my code:

```
def touch_walls(player_pos):

  if x-20 < 0:
    #give warning not to touch sides
    #reset player position

  elif x+20 > 800:
    #give warning not to touch sides
    #reset player position
```

If anyone finds a solution, please tell me.

Comment: What kind of error are you looking for? Would it be just a console output or something else?

Comment: I don't really know, I can just print something, I'm more interested in how to make the code work.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: You need to reset every single game state. There is no magical call to restart the game. Write a function that initializes the game states. Call the function at startup and when the game needs to be restarted.

Answer (score 0):

You can call a function to draw a "Don't touch walls" text.
`

```
def touch_walls(player_pos):

    global playerPos, blit_font_time

    x = player_pos[0]

    if x-20 < 0 or x+20 > 800:
        #make a text varible
        #reset player position
        playerPos = (50, 0)
        blit_font_time = 60 # set this to as long as you wish

def blit_font():
    text = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 50)
    warning_label = text.render('Don\'t Touch Walls', True, (255, 255, 255)) #You can modify the text or the color anyway you want
    center = (screen.get_width()/2 - warning_label.get_width()/2, screen.get_height()/2 - warning_label.get_height()/2)
    screen.blit(warning_label, center) #Blit the text at the center of the screen
```

`

The whole thing will look like this:
`

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

playerPos = (-60, 50) # Assume playerPos is a varible that contains the player's position

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

blit_font_time = 0

def touch_walls(player_pos):

    global playerPos, blit_font_time

    x = player_pos[0]

    if x-20 < 0 or x+20 > 800:
        #make a text varible
        #reset player position
        playerPos = (50, 0)
        blit_font_time = 60 # set this to as long as you wish

def blit_font():
    text = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 50)
    warning_label = text.render('Don\'t Touch Walls', True, (255, 255, 255)) #You can modify the text or the color anyway you want
    center = (screen.get_width()/2 - warning_label.get_width()/2, screen.get_height()/2 - warning_label.get_height()/2)
    screen.blit(warning_label, center) #Blit the text at the center of the screen

run = True

while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    screen.fill((20, 20, 20))

    touch_walls(playerPos)

    if blit_font_time > 0:
        blit_font_time -= 1
        blit_font()
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

`